# asyncio.Semaphore(2) does not limit amount of subprocesses to 2

Tags: python, python-asyncio, semaphore

I am using `asyncio` throughout my application. In the application an external program is started, but I want to limit the maximum amount of external concurrent processes to 2, that's why I am using `Semaphore(2)` like so:

```
async def myfunc(args):
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(args)
    returncode = await proc.wait()

sem = asyncio.Semaphore(2)
async with sem:
    result = await myfunc("some arguments")
```

When I send 3 requests one after the other, and I check `top` command (it's on Linux), I see 3 processes running at the same time. I expected to see 2 process running at the same time, and then as soon as one of those is done, the third one will be started. Am I using `Semaphore(2)` incorrectly?

Comment: not sure if that's the problem, but you should also `await` the process creation at  `create_subprocess_shell`

Comment: Oh that's a typo, I am indeed awaiting the process creation in my code.

Comment: We need a bit more context. You talk about requests. How are you handling these requests? Are all requests going through the same `Semaphore` instance? Or does each request go through its own instance? Or are you using some sort of application server that routes requests to different workers, each with their own `Semaphore` instance?

Answer (score 1):

You should write codes like this, make sure the semaphore uses the same loop with your myfunc, the following codes works fine with me:

```
import asyncio


async def myfunc(cmd, sem):
    async with sem:
        print('start')
        proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(cmd)
        returncode = await proc.wait()
        return returncode


async def main():
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(2)
    cmd = 'python -c "import time; time.sleep(3)"'
    tasks = [myfunc(cmd, sem), myfunc(cmd, sem), myfunc(cmd, sem)]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    assert results == [0, 0, 0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: I'm getting error: `list index out of range`. My code is a bit different than your example: 
`sem = asyncio.Semaphore(2) 
 task = [myfunc("some args", sem)] 
 result = await asyncio.gather(*task, return_exceptions=True)`

Comment: What's your python version, mine is 3.9.

Comment: Python version 3.7.3

Comment: Please double-check your codes, there should not be so much gap, between 3.7 with 3.9, and besides, the demo I posted seems has nothing to do with list except for the tasks.

Comment: I figured out what the error was, it had to do with the way `result = await asyncio.gather(task)` returns the result, it's a tuple inside a list.

Comment: I have set Semaphore(1) to allow only 1 process, tested it again by sending 2 requests very quickly one after another, but saw the process in `top` twice.

Comment: I think your two requests are under two different python threads, due to you are testing it under your website. My demo codes are under the same thread. For your case, you may have to use a redis-lock to work as a semaphore in practice.